# htaccess - get content on one url from another url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there the opportunity to get content on one url from another url? like this:

`test.com/dir1` shows content from query `test.com/getinfo/index.php?q=dir1`

or

`test.com/dir2` shows content from query `test.com/getinfo.php?q=dir2`

I need that because i must do 50 urls like test.com/dir1 ../dir50 which has the same template but with some different content based on query and one virtual url with query is better than 50 real directories.

I tried do but couldnt! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If it is all on the same host, then have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which can do amazing things. Just make sure you read the manual through, as there are a lot of details to take in.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dir1$ /getinfo/index.php?q=dir1 [L]
```

or more generically:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dir(.*)$ /getinfo/index.php?q=dir$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dir1$ getinfo/index.php?q=dir1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks! 

This work only with Redirect=301

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir1$ getinfo/index.php?q=dir1 [R=301,L]

But the questions was - Is there the opportunity to get content on one url from another url without redirecting to new url?:

if i enter test.com/dir1 the url must be the same without redirecting to getinfo/index.php?q=dir1 but information must be which give getinfo/index.php?q=dir1

sorry for my english :)

Comment: If you add the [R=301] you get an external redirect (HTTP 301). If you drop that, you get an internal redirect (just the contents from the redirected URL). The [L] is just there to make sure processing stops at that directive.